# "Suspended" vs "Blocked" meaning

Tags: meaning, differences

What's the difference between:

```
Process A is suspended.
```

And

```
Process A is blocked.
```

(Process refers to process running on computer).

Comment: I don't have any privileges here, yet, but if I did, I would proposing that this question be moved to Programmers SE or Stack Overflow.

Comment: This appears to be a question best settled by reading the fine manual.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on StackOverflow or a related site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect this belongs on a computer-oriented SE. A process is *blocked* when there is some external reason that it *can not* be restarted, e.g., an I/O device is unavailable, or a semaphore file is locked. A process is *suspended* means that the OS has stopped executing it, but that could just be for time-slicing (multitasking). There is no implication that the process can not be resumed immediately.

Neither of these words, especially *blocked,* are being used the same as in non-computer contexts.